# PHPMyAdmin gives "Host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" error

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, centos7

I am working on Centos 7, trying to get everything to work in Docker.
I've set up Nginx and PHP-FPM successfully - both of them work and display everything like they are supposed to. I made so I can open them up with Docker-compose.
After that, I made this paragraph in Docker-compose:

```
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:latest"
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Myregion
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123123
    volumes: 
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I set up TZ to my region, no worries here.
As you see, I specifically requested for an example that MySQL's password is set to "123123". But when I try to log into it with "mysql -u root -p", it denies - says the password the incorrect. But when I leave it empty, I can log into it - for an unknown reason the password is empty.
I thought it might work and did set up PHPMyAdmin in Docker-compose:

```
phpmyadmin: 
    image: "phpmyadmin:latest"
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Myreqion
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

And after that I get PHPMyAdmin window in browser and I can't log in! At all!
Sometimes it gives the "Host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" error, sometimes it gives the error "Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)".
I can't add a new user, I can't grant myself privileges or edit tables (because MySQL suddenly says that I don't have access to do so, but I am in the wheel permissions group) and I can't do anything at all.
This has stopped me for a week. Any ideas?

---

Solution: grant yourself administrator privileges while installing this VM.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the running mysql in Docker? My guess that the mysql is not in Docker. I remembered installing mysql from yum, and able to login without password with user `root`.

PS: I tried your docker-compose script exactly (except TZ of course), my ip is 192.168.0.3, and I was able to login to that IP from phpmyadmin.

Comment: Nevermind, I redid the whole VM and specifically made myself an admin. It works like a charm now - thank you nonetheless!)